# Spring MVC instantiates a new Bean instead of reusing the old one in the Model (@ModelAttribute)

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I think my problem is rather simple, but it's been 2 days and I can't figure it out:

I am new to Spring MVC and I am trying to implement a simple @Controller that handles a form.

- GET request: I add a new PortfolioBean attribute to the Model.
- POST request: I expect to receive a @ModelAttribute with the same PortfolioBean.

@Controller

```
public class FormController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getForm(Model model) {
    PortfolioBean portfolio = new PortfolioBean();
    model.addAttribute("portfolio", portfolio);
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postForm(@ModelAttribute("portfolio") PortfolioBean portfolio) {
    System.out.println("Received portfolio: " + portfolio.getId());
    return "showMessage";
  }
}
```

Here is my JSP view:

```
...
<form:form action="form" commandName="portfolio" method="post">
    Name : <form:input path="name" />
    Nick Name : <form:input path="nickName" />
    Age : <form:input path="age" />
    Mobile : <form:input path="mobNum" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form:form>
```

And here is my PortfolioBean:

```
public class PortfolioBean {
private String name;
private String nickName;
private int age;
private String mobNum;

private static int count = 0;
private int id;

public PortfolioBean() {
    count++;
    id = count;
    System.out.println("NEW BEAN: " + id);
}
    // setters & getters
}
```

As you can see, I added a static count variable to assign incremental IDs, and a println("NEW BEAN!") on the constructor.

My problem is that when I POST the form, **I don't receive my original Bean object, instead Spring instantiates a new one**, but I want my old Bean :(

Log:

```
GET /form
NEW BEAN: 1

POST /form
NEW BEAN: 2
Received portfolio: 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Model` attribute only exist in the context of **one** request. Towards the end of handling the request, the `DispatcherServlet` adds all the attributes to the `HttpServletRequest` attributes.

In your first request, you add a `Model` attribute and it becomes available for use in your `jsp`.

In your second request, because of the `@ModelAttribute`, Spring will try to create an instance from your request's request parameters. This will be a completely different instance as the previous one no longer exists.

If you want to reference the old object, you need to store it in a context that spans multiple requests. You can use `HttpSession` attributes for that purpose, either directly or through flash attributes. You might want to look into `RedirectAttributes` and `@SessionAttributes`.

Comment: oooh now I understand, thanks:) Is there any way to always work on the same bean? I have read something on `<bean id="sessionLogFile" class="somethin.SomeBean" scope="session">
  <aop:scoped-proxy  />
 </bean>`

Comment: @Darkean That is a different use case than using `Model` attributes. If you want to reuse the same bean, let Spring manage it and autowire it into your controller. Careful with multithreading.